# Excel unable to subtract dates in "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" format

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula, formatting, ms-office

I have 2  adjacent columns in excel, each having dates in "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" format. But when I try to subtract them in the third column, it is unable to  give me a numerical value, instead it shows the text "#value!" in the cell. How do I get the time difference between the 2 dates - 
[image]

Comment: Then the "Dates" are text and not true Dates.  You will need to convert them to true dates.  My guess is that your local settings are `mm/dd/yyyy` not `dd/mm/yyyy` and as such Excel does not see them as dates.

Comment: how can i convert all my cells (atleast 100) to true dates? maybe using a formula?

Comment: Use Text to Columns, it is on the data tab.

Comment: Done. Now how do i merge the text segments of the date to true date?

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/26/excel-convert-text-date/

Comment: thanks man ! appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered behalf of **Scott Craner**

Then the "Dates" are text and not true Dates. You will need to convert them to true dates. My guess is that your local settings are mm/dd/yyyy not dd/mm/yyyy and as such Excel does not see them as dates

Check below link to know more.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/26/excel-convert-text-date/